# EMI/UCP question: where do I post?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

`EMI` is a protocol to encode data to be send throught a SMS gateway text messages to final users (it does other things as well).

I would post a `EMI` message to ask direction about how to answer to it. Just to clarify:

The following is the text "super user" sent from user with cell number '00393404679818' to service 3399903107

```
11/00106/O/52/3399903107/00393404679818/////////////140916082853////3//53757065722075736572/////////////82
```

How to acknowledge it positively? (I would say:

```
11/00043/R/52/A//3399903107:140916082853/51
```

but I am not sure).

I am really uncertain to which site ask help about it. Stack Overflow (not much about programming, actually, more about protocols)? Server Fault? Or even Electrical Engineering?

Answer (score 1):

The main question is: how do you intend to answer that service? If it is through a network tool, Super User might be an appropriate place. There are several tags about networking and protocols so that seems to be okay, like the [tcp](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tcp) tag.

If you are using a programming language and you are wondering how to get some data over the network, Stack Overflow can be the right place. As long as you don't ask: *here I have a protocol and a message, please write the code for me*, you will be fine.

Comment: I added an example in the question as maybe it was not clear. My problem is not about how to code the message, but how to compose it. My doubts are about the protocol rules.

Comment: Protocols should be okay on SuperUser too. See the tcp tag for some examples.